# Maximum update depth exceeded when trying to conditionally render content based on useState value

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to conditionally render content on the page based on what link is clicked in the "drawer". But whenever I try rendering the content it gives the error of maximum update exceeded.

It happens in Sidebar.js when I add the <Navigate> tag but I'm not sure how it's causing this.

Here is my code:

// App.js routes

```
...
<Route path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardContents />}>
    <Route path="/dashboard/home" element={<Activity/>}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard/create" element={<CreateInvoice/>} />
    <Route path="/dashboard/list" element={<MyInvoices/>} />
</Route>
...
```

// Sidebar.js

```
...

function Sidebar(props) {
    const [activeLink, changeLinkState] = useState({
        activeItem: { icon: <HomeIcon />, text: "Home" },
        objects: [
            { icon: <HomeIcon />, text: "Home" },
            { icon: <NoteAddIcon />, text: "Create Invoice" },
            { icon: <InboxIcon />, text: "My Invoices" },
        ],
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Drawer
                sx={{
                    width: drawerWidth,
                    flexShrink: 0,
                    "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
                        width: drawerWidth,
                        boxSizing: "border-box",
                    },
                }}
                variant="persistent"
                anchor="left"
                open={props.sideBarState}
            >
                <DrawerHeader>
                    <IconButton onClick={props.onChange}>
                        <ChevronLeftIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </DrawerHeader>
                <Divider />
                <DrawerList activeLink={activeLink} changeLinkState={changeLinkState} />
            </Drawer>

            <Main open={props.sideBarState}>
                <DrawerHeader />
                {/* <Navigate to="/dashboard/create" /> */}
                {activeLink.activeItem.text == "Home" && <Navigate to="/dashboard/home" />}
                {activeLink.activeItem.text == "Create Invoice" && <Navigate to="/dashboard/create" />}
                {activeLink.activeItem.text == "My Invoices" && <Navigate to="/dashboard/list" />}
            </Main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

// DrawerList

```
...

export default function DrawerList(props) {
    const activeLink = props.activeLink;
    const changeLinkState = props.changeLinkState;

    function handleLinkChange(index) {
        changeLinkState({ ...activeLink, activeItem: activeLink.objects[index] });
    }

    function toggleStyles(type, index) {
        if (type === "icon") {
            if (activeLink.objects[index] == activeLink.activeItem) {
                return activeIcon;
            } else {
                return linkContent;
            }
        } else if (type === "text") {
            if (activeLink.objects[index] == activeLink.activeItem) {
                return activeText;
            } else {
                return linkContent;
            }
        } else if (type === "background") {
            if (activeLink.objects[index] == activeLink.activeItem) {
                return { padding: 3, ...activeHighlight };
            } else {
                return { padding: 3 };
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <List>
                {activeLink.objects.map((element, index) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div key={index} onClick={() => handleLinkChange(index)}>
                            <ListItem sx={toggleStyles("background", index)} button>
                                <ListItemIcon sx={toggleStyles("icon", index)}>{element.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary={element.text} sx={toggleStyles("text", index)} />
                            </ListItem>
                        </div>
                        {index === 0 && <Divider />}
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
            </List>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: The `Navigate` component issues the navigation action when it's rendered. What are you trying to accomplish? Why aren't you using links?

Comment: Thanks using Links worked! Routing has been confusing me for a while, but I get what the Navigate component is for now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Navigate` component, when rendered, issues a declarative navigation immediately. What you likely want to use is the `Link` component instead. This is the component that renders an anchor tag and handles navigating to other pages within your app ***after*** being clicked on, not when they are rendered.

```
<Main open={props.sideBarState}>
  <DrawerHeader />
  {activeLink.activeItem.text === "Home" && (
    <Link to="/dashboard/home">
      {activeLink.activeItem.text}
    </Link>
  )}
  {activeLink.activeItem.text === "Create Invoice" && (
    <Link to="/dashboard/create">
      {activeLink.activeItem.text}
    </Link
  }
  {activeLink.activeItem.text === "My Invoices" && (
    <Link to="/dashboard/list">
      {activeLink.activeItem.text}
    </Link>
  }
</Main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved - using Links instead of Navigate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).